# Implementing different objects for each side of the cube in multi-image tracking Vuforia - unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am trying to build an AR application with a cube using vuforia and Multi-Image Target system. I am able to make an object appear in the place of the cube. But i would like to have different objects when the camera scans different sides of the cube. Any suggestions or ideas about how i can do it?

I have tried using the angle of the object with respect to the camera

Comment: Have you considered using multiple image targets instead of Multi-Image target system? That sounds more suitable for your case. If you have an image target for each surface of your cube you can visualize the related model to that image. Only problem is tracking more than 1 image at certain angles but this wil occur even if you the Multi-Image target system based on your scenario.

Comment: I am already using multi-image target system. My question was how to make different objects appear for each side of the Multi-Image target.

Comment: I understand that but what i am saying is instead of using multi-image target system ,which is intended for different scenarios compared to yours, just use regular image targets like astronaut, fissure or drone from example, on each face of your cube

Answer (score 0):

After trying different methods i decided to use ray-casters from each face of the cube and trigger different objects on the same multi-image target. This method is better than using extended tracking and is more stable.